# Rearrange words using Levenshtein distance

Tags: php, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

**Summary**

I am trying to find name matching percentage in php but before that I need to rearrange the words in string according to 1st string.

**What is the source code about?**

I have two strings. First I am adding both strings to array if space is found in string add it into array.
$arraydataBaseName and $arraybankData from my first array i.e $arraydataBaseName I am searching all the values of $arraybankData and getting the Key. I am getting the key arrangement properly but unable to arrange the value at their specific places into new array.

```
$dataBaseName = "Jardine Lloyd Thompson";
$bankdata = "Thompson Thompson Jardine"; 

$replacedataBaseName = preg_replace("#[\s]+#", " ", $dataBaseName);
$replacebankData = preg_replace("#[\s]+#", " ", $bankdata); 

$arraydataBaseName = explode(" ",$replacedataBaseName);
$arraybankData = explode(" ",$replacebankData); 

echo "<br/>";
print_r($arraydataBaseName);

$a="";
$i="";
$arraysize =  count($arraydataBaseName);

$push=array();
for($i=0;$i< $arraysize;$i++)
{     
  if(array_search($arraybankData[$i],$arraydataBaseName)>0)
  {
    ${"$a$i"} =  array_search($arraybankData[$i],$arraydataBaseName); 
    //echo ${"$a$i"};
    array_push($push,${"$a$i"});
   }    
 }
 print_r($push);
```

### Case 1:

**Input**

DatabaseName = Jardine Lloyd Thompson

BankName = Thompson Jardine Lloyd

**Output**

ExpectedOutput = Jardine Lloyd Thompson

### Case 2:##

**Input**

DatabaseName = Jardine Lloyd Thompson

BankName = Thoapson Jordine Llayd

If the words are not found in the above DatabaseName then the expected search would be based on leventish algorithm word which have less distance that would be considered as the key

**Output**

ExpectedOutput = Jordine Llayd Thoapson

[Description of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svhlv.jpg)

### Question Update

When the user input `$bankdata` contains more words remaining unmatchable, I need to append those to the end.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I have been successful to get the position of words by comparing $bankdata with $dataBaseName

Comment: Nice homework! Is there a real database involved?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone no its just variable name

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php you have read?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes I am able to find out distance easily. arranging the word is the step where I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple version, finding the best match word by word subsequently.

```
declare (strict_types=1);

$dataBaseName = 'Jardine Lloyd Thompson';

$bankdataRows =
[
  'Thompson Jardine Lloyd',
  'Blaaa  Llayd Thoapson   f***ing user input   Jordine   aso. ',
];

// assume the "database" is already stored trimmed since it is server-side controlled
$dbWords = preg_split("#[\s]+#", $dataBaseName);

foreach ($bankdataRows as $bankdata)
{
  // here we trim the data received from client-side.
  $bankWords = preg_split("#[\s]+#", trim($bankdata));
  $result    = [];

  if(!empty($bankWords))
    foreach ($dbWords as $dbWord)
    {
      $idx   = null;
      $least = PHP_INT_MAX;

      foreach ($bankWords as $k => $bankWord)
        if (($lv = levenshtein($bankWord, $dbWord)) < $least)
        {
          $least = $lv;
          $idx   = $k;
        }

      $result[] = $bankWords[$idx];
      unset($bankWords[$idx]);
    }

  $result = array_merge($result, $bankWords);
  var_dump($result);
}
```

**result**

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "Jardine"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "Lloyd"
  [2] =>
  string(8) "Thompson"
}

array(8) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "Jordine"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "Llayd"
  [2] =>
  string(8) "Thoapson"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "Blaaa"
  [4] =>
  string(7) "f***ing"
  [5] =>
  string(4) "user"
  [6] =>
  string(5) "input"
  [7] =>
  string(4) "aso."
}
```

[See live fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b41b2cdc0fcf00d9f6be340c1c29e9a5b7dd52b1)

You might want to extend this approach first calculating the Levenshtein distance of each possible combination and then select the best entire match.

Comment: Thank you for sharing I am too close with your solution but when I pass $dataBaseName = trim(' jardine  marks llord  thompson');
$bankdataRows =[$dataBaseName,trim('lloyd thodal jardine')]; the output which I am getting is correct but with error **Notice: Undefined offset: 0**   and for this case $dataBaseName = trim(' jardine llord  thompson');
$bankdataRows =[$dataBaseName,trim('lloyd thodal jardine spark')];  when second variable has 4 words if 1 word is unmatchable it should be appended at the end or at the empty space please suggest I have tried but facing some issue

Comment: @daoootim Just append the remaining bank words `$result = array_merge($result, $bankWords);` To preserve the order of the remnant I've converted the sorting into a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @daoootim If there are more issues not previously described in the question, please open a new question facing one specific issue in compliance to the SO policy.

Comment: @ Quasimodo's clone Legend Thanks you are champ

Comment: need your help when i try this names DatabaseName ='E SRINIVAS' and BankName ='SRINIVAS ETTAMALLA' ExpectedOutput = 'ETTAMALLA SRINIVAS' and i am getting this output = 'SRINIVAS ETTAMALLA'

Answer (score 0):

I have broken up the code in case 1 and 2.
But obviously if the var_export is false you do the case 2 code with the same variables.

```
//Case 1:
$DatabaseName = "Jardine Lloyd Thompson";
$BankName = "Thompson Jardine Lloyd";

//Split and sort them
$data = explode(" ", $DatabaseName);
$bank = explode(" ", $BankName);
sort($data);
sort($bank);
Var_export(($data == $bank)); //true

//Case 2
$DatabaseName = "Jardine Lloyd Thompson";
$BankName = "Thoapson Jordine Llayd";

//Split and sort
$data = explode(" ", $DatabaseName);
$bank = explode(" ", $BankName);
sort($data);
sort($bank);

// Loop and accumulate the levenshtein return
$lev = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $name){
    $lev += levenshtein($name, $bank[$key]);
}

echo PHP_EOL . $lev; // 3 letters "off"
```

https://3v4l.org/eP5PE

Example of case 1 and 2 in the same code.

```
$DatabaseName = "Jardine Lloyd Thompson";
$BankName = "Thoapson Jordine Llayd";

$data = explode(" ", $DatabaseName);
$bank = explode(" ", $BankName);
sort($data);
sort($bank);
if($data == $bank){
    echo "true";
    exit;
    // No need to do levenshtein
}

$lev = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $name){
    $lev += levenshtein($name, $bank[$key]);
}

echo PHP_EOL . $lev;
```

https://3v4l.org/RJSiB

Comment: @ Andreas thanks for you answer but need to rearrange the word after finding levenshtein **e.g:  DatabaseName ='E SRINIVAS' and BankName ='SRINIVAS ETTAMALLA' ExpectedOutput = 'ETTAMALLA SRINIVAS'**